# Fix canvas translation after rotate with DOMMatrix

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I'm using DOMMatrix to set transform on a canvas context, but I am not sure how to "fix" the translation after the rotate. Currently the code I've written rotates an image around a given point on the canvas, which works fine. The issue is after the rotation, the translate moves relative to the rotation, which is not what I want. I want the translation to be relative to the canvas.

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-frog-zxqcdh?file=/src/index.js)

I implemented this function which I read "fixes" the translation after rotation, but it doesn't seem to do what I need:

```js
function rotate(x, y, rotation) {
  const panXX = x * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panXY = y * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYY = y * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYX = x * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panX = panXX + panXY;
  const panY = panYY - panYX;
  return { x: panX, y: panY };
}
```

Is there a way of doing this, either by modifying the `rotate` function above, or the `DOMMatrix`, or a different way entirely?

```js
let rotation = 0;
let scale = 1;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let pointerDown = false;

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const imgWidth = 480;
const imgHeight = 300;

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);

const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/3q3kNGh.png";

function onPointerDown(event) {
  pointerDown = true;
  startX = (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth;
  startY = (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight;
}

function onPointerMove(event) {
  if (!pointerDown) return;
  x = lastX + ((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth - startX);
  y = lastY + ((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight - startY);
}

function onPointerUp() {
  pointerDown = false;
  lastX = x;
  lastY = y;
}

window.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
window.addEventListener("pointermove", onPointerMove);
window.addEventListener("pointerup", onPointerUp);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
  switch (key) {
    case "r":
      rotation = (rotation + 5) % 360;
      break;
    case "-":
      scale = Math.max(0, scale - 0.1);
      break;
    case "=":
      scale = Math.min(2, scale + 0.1);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

function rotate(x, y, rotation) {
  const panXX = x * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panXY = y * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYY = y * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYX = x * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panX = panXX + panXY;
  const panY = panYY - panYX;
  return { x: panX, y: panY };
}

(function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  const imgX = imgWidth * x;
  const imgY = imgHeight * y;

  const { x: tX, y: tY } = rotate(imgX, imgY, rotation);

  const ox = canvas.width / 2 - imgX;
  const oy = canvas.height / 2 - imgY;

  const matrix = new DOMMatrix()
    .translate(ox, oy)
    .rotate(rotation)
    .translate(-ox, -oy)
    .translate(tX, tY)
    .scale(scale);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.setTransform(matrix);

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

  ctx.resetTransform();

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 - 5, canvas.height / 2 - 5, 10, 10);
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
pre {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<pre>
  Hotkeys
  ---
  Rotate: r
  Zoom out: -
  Zoom in: =
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `rotate()` to mouse-movements, it might work as expected.

```
function onPointerMove(event) {
    if (!pointerDown) return;
    
    //x = lastX + ((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth - startX);
    //y = lastY + ((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight - startY);

    let deltaX = (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth - startX;
    let deltaY = (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight - startY;
    const { x: dX, y: dY } = rotate(deltaX * imgWidth, deltaY * imgHeight, rotation);
    x = lastX + dX / imgWidth;
    y = lastY + dY / imgHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Your order of transformations were wrong. Here is the correct one:

```
const matrix = new DOMMatrix()
.translate(imgWidth/2, imgHeight/2)
.rotate(rotation)
.scale(scale)
.translate(-imgWidth/2 + tX / scale, -imgHeight/2 + tY / scale);
```

if you want to rotate around another point, for example canvas center, then replace `imgWidth / 2` with `canvas.width / 2` and `-imgWidth / 2` with `-canvas.width / 2`. Do the same for the height.

You are forgetting that css transformations and canvas/svg transformations are a little bit different. In CSS the origin is the center of the element. In SVG/canvas, the origin is the upper left corner (0,0). IN the latter case, center the object to the origin, apply scale/rotate and THEN do the transformation.

Comment: But it's still not rotating properly. only drag and drop is fixed

Comment: @rooteduser is correct. This solves translation after rotation but breaks my existing rotation code. Your version no longer rotates around the centre any more, since you've removed the ox, oy, -ox, -oy translations

Comment: You rotation function is doing 2 things at a time. Rotate around a point should be 2 functions. Instead you are passing x, y, rotate. And why are you multiplying imgWidth * x or imgHeight * y, the intent is not clear at all.

Comment: x,y is a floating percentage of the width,height of the image so the multiplication of x,y is used to calculate the "real" x,y pixel value of the canvas. This is for responsive reasons

Comment: Could you try the above matrix

Comment: That works, but only for rotating around the image centre, not the canvas centre.

Comment: ? You can easily replace `imgWidth / 2` with `canvas.width / 2` and do the same for the height. When you do `ox = canvas.width / 2 - imgX` you are re-adding that unnecessary subtraction of `imgX/imgY` back to the translations via the rotation. There is no need to divide the rendering logic between 2 places and call extra `rotation` in an unthrottled mouse event. Also you have to call scale before the last translation, otherwise as you increase scale things will shift towards the center.